# Can not import a manual package into Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I created my own package to be used in the Google Cloud ML Engine job.

In order to use my package, I follow the instructions in the [official Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/packaging-trainer?hl=ru#project-structure).

That is, I archived my package into `tar.gz` and upload it into a Cloud Storage bucket.

Next, I start my job and get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 454, in open buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb') FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-iprehs_0/setup.py`

Please advise me the algorithm for importing manual packages, or share a link where this is done.

Comment: Can you try to pip install your package locally please? Your package might not be installable. If you still face the issue, please send your jod id to cloudml-feedback@google.com. Thansk!